# GRANT VIEW on 1 database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, view

Is there any work around to grant view on a particular database after executing the below code?, I am using MS SQL 2008 RC2.

```
REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM <login>;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `REVOKE` wins, so you may need to grant `VIEW ANY` and then deny on all of the other databases individually. This is less fun of course but you can automate this without having to do it one by one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know the sql statement to use to grant/deny the view of a single database because that is actually what I am looking for?

Comment: Should be just `CREATE USER <x> FOR LOGIN <x>;` in the databases where you want them to access, and `DROP USER <x>;` in the databases where they have been created but you now want to deny (just be careful if they have their own schema or have created any objects). Of course this does not deal with what permissions they actually have once they are in that database, but should be a start. From my limited testing it seems the db-level user will override `REVOKE ANY` (and `GRANT ANY` trumps absence in a particular db), but you'll want to test that in your system.

Comment: My scenario is the following. I have 2 databases and a TestUser at server level. I have executed `REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM TestUser`. And now when the user logs in using the managment studio he doesn't have any database visible (Which is good). I have added this user under one of my databases and wish to make that database visible to the user, and I am stuck here because I cannot find the command to make a single database visIbily when connecting with sql managment studio.

Comment: See if this link helps. I actually wrote this and totally forgot: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/07/19/for-shared-sql-server-providers-hiding-your-list-of-databases-from-customers.aspx If you want better support for this scenario please vote for http://connect.microsoft.com/SQL/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=124651 and http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/273830/need-view-definition-permissions-per-database